# trying to compare times in SQL Server via operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to compare dates in MS SQL Server with an operator, but I'm getting the error:

> The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than
>   operator.

```
Select *
from Student
where Student# not in(
    Select distinct Student#
    from Enrolls
    inner join Section on Enrolls.Section# = Section.se# 
    where section_time > DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE())
      And Count(distinct student#) > 6);
```

I've tried casting to variables, but then those variables are undefined or defined improperly. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Is there a `section_date` column as well?

Comment: No GROUP BY needed?!?

Comment: yeah. now I'm getting the following error... 'The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `section_time` has data type **time**.

The expression `DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE())` has data type **datetime**.

Your code does not make sense, since you compare a **time** (which contains only a "time of the day") with a date (and time) two years ago. What is

```
11:30 > 2014-04-01 09:24
```

supposed to return?

Comment: Awesome. I didn't realize I was mixing data types. Rookie mistake by me. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Using 'CAST' As `Time` data type

```
 Select * from Student where Student# not in(
 Select distinct Student# from Enrolls inner join Section on
 Enrolls.Section#=Section.se# 
 where section_time > CAST(DATEADD(year, -2, GETDATE()) AS TIME)
 And
 Count(distinct student#) > 6);
```